# Ionic taivo parse push plugin IOS build error

Tags: ios, cordova, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I am currently working on a cordova project which goes fine. It is done for the android and windows side, but I have been experiencing problem while running on iOS.

I have all programs installed to run ionic on iOS, because it runs normally with a blank project.

What I tried to build my project, but it finished with some error at the parsepushplugin.

This is the error:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/APP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/APP.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVParsePlugin.o APP/Plugins/com.phonegap.parsepushplugin/CDVParsePlugin.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC build/APP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/APP.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.o APP/Classes/AppDelegate.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)
Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/Aron/Documents/Stage/APP/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,APP.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,APP,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/Aron/Documents/Stage/APP/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/Aron/Documents/Stage/APP/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/Aron/Documents/Stage/APP/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /Users/Aron/Documents/Stage/APP/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
```

I hope you guys can help me.

Many thanks.

Comment: Check if you have read/write permissions, for [OS X El Capitan](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21997?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US). I regulary have a similar problem, but I am not quite sure about how I actually solved the problem...

Comment: For the map that contains the project only?

Comment: At least for your project folder

Comment: Checked it and the project for already has read/write permissions. I have also checked the folder that contains the plugin and that also has r/w permissions.

Comment: Already tried re-adding plugin or even the whole platform?

Comment: I re-added the plugin, that works. But the next error is with another plugin called "Themeable" in app browser. I tried to do the same thing with that plugin, but I keep getting the same error. Without that plugin the app build/launch fine.

Comment: Oh my app gets stuck at lauch, does not work well yet.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with ionic push plugin.  Got the same error message when I build ios.  NO solution yet

Comment: Just found a new plugin works fine. https://github.com/yupswing/ParsePlugin